# Where to get the latest statistics on number of websites running on PHP, JAVA, .NET, .Ruby

Tags: java, php, .net, ruby

Curious where I can find the latest statistics that help me find out how different web technologies (PHP, JAVA, .NET, Ruby) are placed in terms of number of websites that they are powering. Given that most web servers provide this information in the response headers, I am sure somebody might be keeping track of this data.

Comment: Most webservers don't provide that information in the header and for good reason - it would make you more vulnerable to exploits.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this: [Usage of server-side programming languages for websites](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all), it's updated daily according to the site.